# Set seed using Rmath.h to compare to R

Tags: c, r, random-seed

I have C code using random number generation through `Rmath.h` that I want to compare with C code called through R.

The c code below is loaded using `R CMD SHLIB` then in R with `dyn.load()` and called with `.C("ranNorm",as.double(0),as.double(1),as.double(1))`

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rmath.h>

void ranNorm(double *mean, double *sd, double *x){
double mean = mean[0];
double sd = sd[0];

GetRNGstate();
x[0] = rnorm(mean, sd);
PutRNGstate();
}
```

And I can set the seed in R using set.seed(). However I want to compare this to the following c code:

```
#define MATHLIB_STANDALONE
#include <Rmath.h>

int main(void){ 
double z;

z = rnorm(0.0,1.0);
printf("%f \n", z); 

return 0;
}
```

Which is compiled and run using `-lRmath`

However I'm not sure how to set the seed with this code to ensure the same result as in the previous code. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Charles Geyer at UMN this is solved! The key is to get R to match C, not the other way around as I was trying.

In C, you use `set_seed(111,222)`, then in R run the commands

```
RNGkind("Marsaglia-Multicarry")
.Random.seed<-c(401L,111L,222L)
```

Voila! Matching R and C code.

Comment: What is the function of `401L` in that invocation?